# C/C++ tool to find most frequent function calls?

Tags: c++

Does anyone know of a Linux CLI tool which can wrap around a running C/C++ program and tell me statistics such as most frequent function calls? I've already looked into valgrind and gdb. Just wondering if there are others out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into `gprof`. The following links give the steps necessary to use `gprof`. Essentially, it will tell you which functions your program is spending the most time and instructions in.

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/

http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/pointers/gprof_quick.html

Definitely go to the UMich link. It has a very clear explanation of how to use `gprof`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.